# Change Page Orientation in RazorPDF2

Tags: razorpdf

I am trying to use the NuGet package RazorPDF2 to convert a Razor View to a PDF.  The tool works wonderfully and is simple to use for just rendering a PDF, but I cannot figure out how to change the page orientation to landscape.

I am using very simple controller code just to test the conversion to PDF.  The conversion works, but I cannot change the orientation.

```
    public ActionResult TrainingCertificate()
    {
        var model = new CertificateModel();
        model.Name = "Michael White";
        return new PdfActionResult("TrainingCertificate", model);
    }
```

The "PdfActionResult" method does have an overload that looks like it might take configuration settings, but I cannot figure out how to use it because the parameter is an "encapsulated" "Action":

```
    public PdfActionResult(string viewName, object model, Action<iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter, iTextSharp.text.Document> configureSettings) : base(viewName, model, configureSettings)
    {
        
    }
```

Does anyone have any experience with this tool or can help with figuring out what is needed for the "configurationSettings" parameter, please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured this one out.  I changed the return "PdfActionResult" code to the following:

```
        return new PdfActionResult("TrainingCertificate", model, (writer, document) =>
        {
            document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
            document.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
            document.NewPage();
        });
```